# How do I set my gpu_split?

Tags: gpu, crash, memory-split

My Emulation Station keeps crashing saying I need to make sure my gpu_split is set high enough and/or switch back to carbon theme. Can someone help me dial this in? Any thoughts or suggestions are much appreciated as I dunno what's causing my ES to randomly keep crashing.

RP3b (not sure if its a B+ or not. Its a model B v1.2 from 2015)
running RetroPie 4.5.1
I mostly use pixel-metadata theme.
I scraped for metadata and have a video, image, thumbnail, and marquee for almost each ROM (1500+ games)
I have a 128GB SD card that's only about 50% filled atm.
Setup from a stock RP image about a week ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vcgencmd` to get the memory:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ vcgencmd get_mem gpu
gpu=128M
```

Alternatively use `raspi-config` non-interactively, which uses `vcgencmd` underneath and pulls out just the number:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo raspi-config nonint get_config_var gpu_mem /boot/config.txt
128
```

Comment: You are answering how to **get** the memory but the question was how to **set** it. As far as I know you can set it in `/boot/config.txt`. If you know how you may add it to the answer?

Comment: You can set it with e.g. `raspi-config nonint do_memory_split 256`

Comment: You should add the information to the answer.